# Showing multivariable maps are smooth

Tags: multivariable-calculus, smooth-functions

How does one in practice actually show a map is smooth?

Say I am considering:
$$F:B^n\to \Bbb R^n,\qquad F(x) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-\|x\|^2}},$$
where $B^n$ is the open unit ball in $\Bbb R^n$ and $\|x\|$ is the euclidean norm on $\Bbb R^n$.

Smoothness means that all partial derivatives of all orders exist. I can compute the Jacobian matrix, which seems quite ugly, but even still, I can't just deduce that the partial derivatives of all orders exist (and they don't vanish in few steps).

Usually the maps I encounter are obviously smooth, but only because they are polynomial in each entry and what-not, but outside of these cases, I don't know how to approach this. Are there some results that I haven't seen?

How do you actually show such a map is smooth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is smooth because it can be obtained from smooth functions ($x$, square root, and $\lVert x\rVert^2$) using composition and arithmetic opeations.

Comment: So if $f,g:U\to \Bbb R^n$ are smooth, then $f+g, f-g, fg$ are smooth and $f/g$ is smooth if $g\ne 0$ on $U$, and $\sqrt{f}$ is smooth if $f\geq 0$ on $U$, then I just say each $x_i$ is smooth, so $x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2$ is smooth, and it's $\geq 0$ so $\|x\|$ is smooth. Then since $\|x\|<1$ on this ball, $(1-\|x\|)^2>0$ and so $\sqrt{1-\|x\|^2}$ is smooth, and since it's greater than zero, $\frac1{\sqrt{1-\|x\|^2}}$ is smooth, and hence for each $i$, $\frac{x_i}{\sqrt{1-\|x\|^2}}$ is smooth

Comment: That is indeed correct.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why I didn't think of that!

Answer (score 3):

I would go even further and say that smoothness requires all partial derivatives to exist and be **continuous**.

One way to prove smoothness is to find a closed form for each n-th partial derivative. This can be difficult in practice.

For easy functions like yours, you can use the standard result that a sum, multiplication, square root on $(0, +\infty)$, and composition of smooth functions is smooth. You can prove this using the sum/product rules for derivatives and the chain rule.